# How to connect to localhost PostgreSQL on Mac using PSequel GUI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, macos, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-postgresql-on-a-mac-with-homebrew-and-lunchy/) to install PG on my Mac. It's my first time using PG locally. I used Sqlite a lot in my Rails projects before this.

I found this [PSequel GUI app](http://www.psequel.com/) and I just installed it. But I've no idea how to connect to my localhost PostgreSQL databases.

[image]

What is my:

1. Host/Socket?
2. Port? (I use `localhost:3000` to test my Rails app locally)
3. User?
4. Password?
5. Database?

Thanks.

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 7):

`localhost:3000` is the default url of [webrick](/questions/tagged/webrick) webserver. By default postgre SQL service connection is to `localhost` on `5432` post.

```
$ cat /etc/services | grep postgres
postgres    5432/tcp            # POSTGRES
postgres    5432/udp            # POSTGRES
```

That is for `unix` like systems. And I have `postgres` server listening on `5432` port.

```
$ netstat -l  --numeric-ports |grep 5432
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdomain:5432  *:* 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11396  /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

So the fields will have the following default values:

1. *Host/Socket*

   ```
   localhost
   ```

   For test/development purposes most people use local server to connect to db.
2. *Port*

   ```
   5432
   ```

   That is just `postgres` server (not webserver) connection port. To validate just list and grep the `postgres` configuration file, like follows:

   ```
   # cat /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf | grep port
   #port = 5432                # (change requires restart)
   ```

   Here it is commented out, so default values are applied.
3. *User*

   you are, but you must [create the user role](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-createuser.html) before connection as of the `postgres` user with `createuser` or `psql` terminal utilities.
4. *Password*

   When you will create the user just leave password empty. So you be able then stay the field empty in the form.
5. *Database*

   That is the database name. [Create](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/manage-ag-createdb.html) it with the command if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should enter below detail for configuration:

> Host/Socket? - localhost
>
> Port? - 5432
>
> User? - DB user(My case its: postgres)
>
> Password? - Password for above user
>
> Database? - DB name of your project

You can see [image: this] screenshot in this site: http://www.psequel.com/