# Connecting to localhost PostgreSQL on Mac using PSequel GUI?

Tags: postgresql, user-interface, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-postgresql

I have used Sequel Pro as a GUI to connect to databases with previous projects which were done using Laravel 5.4.  It seemed simple enough to connect to the database using the Sequel Pro GUI.  I have tried following the following tutorial [Rails and link to a PSequel GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32837134/how-to-connect-to-localhost-postgresql-on-mac-using-psequel-gui)

These are the setting I have.[image]
This is the error I am getting. [image]
What do I need to do to configure it for the GUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default postgres port is 5432. As I see from the screenshot, you are trying to connect to port 3000. So at least you should change port to 5432 if you have default postgres setup.